# Jquery toggle with unknown number of items

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamically created content where there could be 2 or there could be 200 DIV's - each div has some content I want to toggle and an arrow to show the content.

I can get toggle etc to work fine but when it toggles it toggles everything (i.e. all the items with the class name - as it should) but I only want it to toggle the relevant one.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="expanded">
                12345
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="expanded">
                12345
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="expanded">
                12345
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I have tried suggestions from [toggling dynamically created divs in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577461/toggling-dynamically-created-divs-in-jquery) to use on and from [Toggle dynamically created divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563507/toggle-dynamically-created-divs) to use next/prev but when I use these nothing happens and there is nothing in DevTools to help

Can anyone point me in the right direction so when I click each arrow only its expanded box appears? http://jsfiddle.net/pgJf4/

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pgJf4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the expanded element within the same `inner` element

```
$(".arrow-down").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.inner').find('.expanded').toggle("slow");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fbu99/)

- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: It would probably be useful to use event delegation instead. That way there is only a single event handler, and you don't need to reapply the click handlers when new elements are added: http://jsfiddle.net/Fbu99/2/

Comment: @Munter yes if the items are added dynamically then event delegation might be required

Answer (score 0):

use this to get target element

```
$( ".arrow-down" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.expanded').toggle( "slow" );
});
```